# Decrementing Function Arguments (PYTHON)

Tags: python, function, pygame, arguments

I'm calling functions similar to those that follow, inside a loop:

```
    def bigAnim(tick,firstRun):
        smallAnim(x,y,duration)
        #more anims and logic...



    def smallAnim(x, y,duration):
        duration -= 1
        if duration != 0:
            Anim.blit(screen,(x ,y))
            Anim.play()


        else:
            Anim.stop()
            loopedOnce = True
            return loopedOnce
```

Now say I were to call the smallAnim inside the big anim as follows:

```
    def bigAnim(tick,firstRun):
        smallAnim(0,50,5)
```

smallAnim is now being called indefinitely, as duration will never go lower than 4 (being reset to 5 every time it's called in the loop). What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Dont pass duration in as '5'.. instead pass it as a variable that can be decremented and re-evaluated on its next iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the counting in `bigAnim` and only call `smallAnim()` when the value is greater than zero.

Or you can return the current duration:

```
def bigAnim(tick,firstRun):
    duration = smallAnim(x,y,duration)
    #more anims and logic...

def smallAnim(x, y, duration):
    duration -= 1
    if duration > 0:
        Anim.blit(screen,(x ,y))
        Anim.play()
    return duration
```

Your underlying problem is [Python does pass the references to the variables, but integers are *immutable*.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

This is a little easier to understand with strings:

The function

```
def foo(s):
    s = " world"
```

will only modify `s` local to the function if you call `foo("hello")`.  The typical pattern you'll see instead is:

```
def foo(s):
    return s + " world"
```

And then ... `print foo("hello")`